# Why does DbSet.Add change properties of other entities?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a rare case where the call of `DbSet<T>.Add()` changes some properties of other entities that are already in the `DbSet<T>`. Unfortunately, it happens very rarely, and the only evidence I have are some log files, so I have not yet been able to reproduce it locally.

The behavior is like this:

1. First, we load some entities from the `DbSet` using a LINQ query.
2. Then, some of these entities are changed. No `SaveChanges()` yet.
3. Now we add some entities by calling `DbSet<T>.Add()`.

Some of the entities of step 2 are changed in step 3 (one foreign-key property of them is set to `null`).

Any idea? Is that something that can happen on a EF 6 Code-First model?

The only possibility I can think of is that the `DbContext` refreshes some data from the database, but we don't want it to do that at this point.

**EDIT:** The code is currently scattered with log statements, since we have been chasing this bug since weeks. These are the relevant code sections:

```
// parameter: List<Entry> entriesFromUser

var entriesFromDb = db.Entries
    .Where(...)
    .OrderBy(...)
    .ToList();

var newEntries = MergeEntries(entriesFromDb, entriesFromUser);

var propertyBefore = entriesFromDb[0].MyForeignKeyId;
for (var i = 0; i < newEntries.Count; i++)
{
    // make sure that the "new entry" is not a modified one
    if (entriesFromDb.Contains(newEntries[i])
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    db.Entries.Add(newEntries[i]);
}

var propertyAfter = entriesFromDb[0].MyForeignKeyId;

Debug.Assert(propertyBefore == propertyAfter);          // <=== fails sometimes

db.SaveChanges();
```

Please note that the changed foreign key is **NOT** on the entity being added to the `DbSet`. It's on an entity that comes from the database, but has been changed in the same transaction.

Comment: Please show the code that executes these steps. I can imagine that adding entities changes FK values, but only your code can confirm that.

Comment: Ermm yeah, that doesn't tell me much about relationships between the entities. What could possibly happen here is that a new entity "steals" a reference from an existing entity.

Comment: Is there any documentation about this "reference stealing"? Btw the foreign key I'm talking about is N:1.

Comment: What do you mean by *a new entity "steals" a reference from an existing entity*? Is that documented EF 6 code-first behavior?

Comment: Well just that if existing B is a child of existing A and there a new C that takes B as child this could lead to B getting a different FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh. Found the reason. Hope it helps someone else.

We are using [Foreign Key Associations](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/), which means that we have both the navigation property `entry.MyForeignKey` and the Foreign Key property `entry.MyForeignKeyId`, which has many advantages, but it also means you have to be careful when using sometimes this, sometimes that property.

Turns out we had the following assignment somewhere deep in the code, where all the data of one entry is copied to another one:

```
entry.MyForeignKeyId = otherEntry.MyForeignKeyId
entry.MyForeignKey = otherEntry.MyForeignKey
```

However, in many scenarios, you set a foreign key value to an entity's `MyForeignKeyId` but leave the property `MyForeignKey` null, because the parent entity is not loaded. This is fine as long as you don't **assign null** to the entity's `MyForeignKey` property, because it seems that EF would then set `MyForeignKeyId` to null too.

So it seems that after our code assigned null to `MyForeignKey`, the entity lingered in memory with a null `MyForeignKey` and a non-null `MyForeignKeyId`. As soon as the next `DbSet` command was executed (the `Add()` operation), the `DbSet` noticed that `MyForeignKey` has received a `null` assignment, so `DbSet` went on and assigned `null` to `MyForeignKeyId` too.